# Find mean and standard deviation using loops

Tags: java, loops, standard-deviation

My goal is to calculate the **mean** and **standard deviation** of 10 numbers obtained from user input.

I learned only *while loops* in my class.

**Question:**
How can I assign each user input (inside the loop) to a separate variable, to later compare to the mean, to find the standard deviation?

*(I haven't taught about arrays in my class. So, I have to solve this without using arrays)*

*I did the program a very long a tedious way but can provide more code if needed to show I can do while loops to find mean.*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StandardDev
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

   double num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 = 0, num5 = 0, num6 = 0, num7 = 0, num8 = 0, num9 = 0, num10 = 0, total = 0, mean = 0, stDev1 = 0, stDev2 = 0, sum = 0;

   System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers: ");
   num1 = input.nextDouble();
   num2 = input.nextDouble();
   num3 = input.nextDouble();
   num4 = input.nextDouble();
   num5 = input.nextDouble();
   num6 = input.nextDouble();
   num7 = input.nextDouble();
   num8 = input.nextDouble();
   num9 = input.nextDouble();
   num10 = input.nextDouble();

   sum = num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9+num10;

   mean = sum / (double) 10;

   stDev1 = Math.pow(num1 - mean, 2) + Math.pow(num2 - mean, 2) + Math.pow(num3 - mean, 2) + Math.pow(num4 - mean, 2) + Math.pow(num5 - mean, 2) + 
   Math.pow(num6 - mean, 2) + Math.pow(num7 - mean, 2) + Math.pow(num8 - mean, 2) + Math.pow(num9 - mean, 2) + Math.pow(num10 - mean, 2);

   stDev2 = Math.sqrt(stDev1 / 10);

   System.out.println ("The mean is " + mean + ".");
   System.out.println ("The standard deviation is " + stDev2 + ".");
   }
}
```

Here is what I have for finding mean. My logic tells me I can only find standard deviation if I can access those inputs individually to subtract from mean and square. Not sure how though..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JTillman03_45
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

   int count = 0, total = 0;

   double mean, stDev = 0;

   System.out.println("Enter a digit: ");
   int number = input.nextInt();

   while (count < 9){
      total += number;
      count++;


   System.out.println("Enter a digit: ");
   number = input.nextInt();
   }

   mean = total / (double) count;

   System.out.println("The mean of those numbers is: " + mean); 
   System.out.println("The standard deviation of those numbers is: " + stDev); 
  }
}
```

Comment: An array would work nicely here. Do you know if it is acceptable to use one?

Comment: Its just use of loops. I have modified this program and updated below

Comment: @MatthewCliatt we can't use an array because 1) we have not discussed them in class 2) I do not know how to use arrays lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to store all the integers?  If not, you can compute the average and standard deviations with the three following values:

1. How many numbers were entered (in your problem, it is a fixed value 10).
2. The sum of all numbers.
3. The sum of the squares of the numbers.

Which gives

```
double count = 10.0;   // is 10.0 for your problem
double sum1 = 0.0;    // sum of the numbers
double sum2 = 0.0;    // sum of the squares
int i;
for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers: ");
  double n = input.nextDouble();
  sum1 += n;
  sum2 += n * n;
}
double average = sum1 / count;
double variance = (count * sum2 - sum1 * sum1) / (count * count);
double stdev = Math.sqrt(variance);
```

Comment: Ahh. This is perfect. I couldn't think of any other way to calculate it other than storing all 10 integers. Visually seeing this helps me understand the calculation more thoroughly. So instead of performing the calculation per integer, you can just perform it at the end using the different sums.

Answer (score 0):

For summing up 10 user-inputted numbers, you can keep track of the sum using just one variable and the += operator. No need to have so many variables, that's what the loop is for! For example,

```
double sum = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
int counter = 1;
System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers: ");
//adds up 10 user-inputted numbers
while(counter <= 10){
     sum += input.nextDouble();
     //how the loop will end after 10th iteration
     counter++;
}
double mean = sum/10; //no need for double cast here since sum is a double
```

Without arrays, it would be hard to calculate the standard deviation using loops since we need access to the individual numbers to find the standard deviation. Therefore, your solution is really the only way unless we have the user input the same 10 numbers again using a while loop similar to above to find the variance. For example,

```
//reset counter
counter = 1;
double variance = 0;
System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers: ");

while(counter <= 10){
     variance += Math.pow(input.nextDouble()-mean,2);
     counter++;
}
double stdDev = Math.sqrt(variance/10);
System.out.println ("The mean is " + mean + ".");
System.out.println ("The standard deviation is " + stdDev + ".");
```

Comment: what do you mean? I am merely just providing an example using loops like the user asked for? since the user cannot use arrays, this is just a possible solution to his problem.

Answer (score -1):

Using a `while` loop, iterate the values of `input.nextDouble()` as the condition of the loop. as long as there is input, the loop will keep going. At the same time, keep a count of the number of inputs and the sum of the numbers. Just with those 2 numbers, you can calculate the mean and the standard deviation. If you look at `stDev1` you can see it is just the sum of the numbers minus the mean times 10 (or the count of inputs). The mean is just the sum divided by the count of inputs. If you need more explanations, let me know. I will be adding some example code shortly.

```
public class StandardDev {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            sum += input.nextDouble();
            count++;
        }
        mean = sum / count;
        stdDev = sum - (count * mean);

        System.out.println("The mean is " + mean + ".");
        System.out.println("The standard deviation is " + stdDev + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but how will I access those inputs individually to subtract from the mean and then square them?

Comment: This doesn't give the right answer for standard-deviation.

Answer (score -1):

Here is updated code with loops.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double sum = 0;
    double sqSum = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers: separte by space");
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        double val = input.nextDouble();
        sum += val;
        sqSum += val * val;
    }

    double mean = sum / 10;
    double stdDev = sqSum / 10 - mean * mean;
    System.out.println("The mean is " + mean + ".");
    System.out.println("The standard deviation is " + stdDev + ".");
}
```

Comment: this can be achieved with a single loop

Comment: Yes sure we could do that

Comment: Note that the poster does not wish to use arrays.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt thanks for pointing that. I have modified my answer .

Comment: The function you use for stdDev is for the variance.  The standard deviation is the square root of the variance.